# writing pandas data frame into xml

Tags: html, pandas

I want to write my pandas data frame into xml .
My dataframe looks like this

```
Col1 Col2  Value 
a     b    5

c     d   6
```

My xml output should look like this

```
<Root>
    <Expense>
            <Col1>a</Col1>
            <Col2>b</Col2>
            <Value>5</Value>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
            <Col1>c</Col1>
            <Col2>d</Col2>
            <Value> 5</Value>
    </Expense>
</Root>
```

Comment: As of pandas 1.3.0 use `df.to_xml('outfile.xml', index=False, root_name='Root', row_name='Expense', xml_declaration=False)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html) :

```
import pandas as pd
# suppose you have a pd.DataFrame my_df

# save the pd.DataFrame to my_df.xml in the same repository :
my_df.to_xml("my_df.xml")
```

---

If your `pandas` version does not support `to_xml`, you can convert it to `JSON` then use [`json2xml`](https://pypi.org/project/json2xml/).

Comment: NOTE: -> This is `New in version 1.3.0`.

Comment: I am getting the following error while trying to use  df.to_xml                 
        AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_xml'

Comment: then you must check your pandas version (cf @Nk03's comment) for example by doing `pip list | grep pandas` or `conda list pandas`

Comment: I see thanks unfortunately we are using version 1.1.3 not 1.3.0

Comment: thanks I will check with team and see which way they want to go

Comment: if tis works for you, would you accept my answer ? thanks !